# Oracle REST Data Services, JSON vs HTML error responses

Tags: oracle, rest, oracle-apex, oracle-ords, oracle-rest-data-services

I have a REST API with POST method and it works fine. But on a custom 400 status code error response the content-type seems to be html rather than json.

**Sample:**

400 , 79ms, 23 bytes

api_status_code: SIM400-05
connection: close
content-type: **text/html**;charset=UTF-8
date: Mon, 13 Jun 2022 14:31:15 GMT
transfer-encoding: chunked
x-ords_debug: false

Invalid Account Number

I have tried adding "REST-Framework-Version" as 4 in my request header but still the error response is as html and not json.

Oracle APEX: 21.1
Oracle ORDS: 21

Comment: `400` is an HTTP protocol-level error, so it is returned as HTTP. JSON content will only be returned by a successful completion (HTTP status 200) of the API call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your request include an Accept header.

```
curl -X POST --header 'Accept: application/json'
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Jeff, Thank you for the response. I am sorry I did not respond here, but I managed to solve this by adding "OWA_UTIL.mime_header('application/json');" before I print the body content, in my ORDS Handler Definition - PLSQL Source. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Add below header in PLSQL code before printing the response message

OWA_UTIL.mime_header('application/json');